# How can I view folders in my own mailbox?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need cmdlet to view folders in my own mailbox.
Get-MailboxFolder isn't available for me cause I have powershell 2.0.
What do I want to see?

```
#Folders:#
inbox
sent
drafts
etc.
```

Comment: Which mail server are you using?

Comment: What do you mean? it's a regular server but not gmail, yahoo and etc.